# Problem looping through nested JavaScript objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, html

i need display the child value, but it display [object, object] like that so

Here my code:

```
var jsonObj = {"department":{
              "Title1":[
                           {"child1":"Green",
                            "child2":"Yellow"
                           },

                           {"child3":"Black",
                            "child4":"White"
                           }
                           ],
              "Title2":[
                           {"child5":"Violet",
                            "child6":"purple"
                           },
                          {"child7":"Pink",
                            "child8":"Orange"
                           }
                           ]
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {

var  treeList = "";
treeList = "<ul id=\"createTree\">";     
for(var key in jsonObj){
        for(var subKey in jsonObj[key]){
        alert(subKey);
        //for(i=0; i<jsonObj[key].length;i++ ) {
           treeList +=  ("<li>" + subKey + "<ul><li>"+jsonObj[key][subKey]+"</li></ul></li>");
           //var b = $(c).text();
           alert(treeList);
       }
    }
treeList += "</ul>";
$('#tree').append(treeList);
});
```

Comment: Consider writing a slightly more descriptive title to your question, short and concise, without necessarily including your entire question in said title...

Comment: There is no JSON in your code. I'd say you have a problem with JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Quentin said you need to keep drilling down, first into the array then into the objects contained within the array. The code below should access all the variables held in the JSON, you might have to restructure the HTML it outputs to get it looking as you want -

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var  treeList = "";
treeList = "<ul id=\"createTree\">";     
for(var key in jsonObj){
        for(var subKey in jsonObj[key]){
        alert(subKey);
        for(i=0; i<jsonObj[key][subKey].length;i++ ) {
           for(var arrayKey in jsonObj[key][subKey][i]){ 
              treeList +=  ("<li>" + subKey + " - " + arrayKey  + " - "+jsonObj[key][subKey][i][arrayKey]+"</li></ul></li>");
           }    
           //var b = $(c).text();
           alert(treeList);
        }   
       }
    }
    treeList += "</ul>";
    $('#tree').append(treeList);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `jsonObj[key][subKey]` will be `jsonObj.department.Title1`. This is an array.

When you stringify an array, it will, by default, produce the generic "This is an object" text.

If you want to display the data in it, you will have to keep going down to get at the strings.